# Cannot login to SQL Server from Visual Studio, same credentials work on SSRS page

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, visual-studio-2013

I am running into a strange issue.  I have a SQL Server login that I use for running reports on SSRS.  When I go to the SSRS page I can modify the stored credentials to use that login:
[image]

Now when I try to build that same login right into the report in Visual Studio I get the following error: [image]

I am not sure why I can login from one place but not the other.  I am using SQL Server 2014 Standard and VS 2013.  Does anyone know what permissions setting needs to be change, or what to do to be able to deploy my report using this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem.  I needed to grant data reader rights to that database for the user.  I do that by right clicking the user name under Security\Logins and choosing properties.  In there I go to User Mapping.  Make sure the user is mapped to the database being queried and under the Database Role Membership make sure db_datareader is checked.